# Refresh minicart in javascript file

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, javascript, requirejs

I have a javascript file like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var mainWindown = top.document;
    test = {
        teesping_vesrion : '1.0.0',
        mainStuff : function(){
            var vars = {};
            this.doStuff();
            //refesh mini cart here
        },
        doStuff : function(){
         ......
        }
    )
})
```

i want to reload the minicart in  my mainStuff function, but i dont know how to integrate the below code to my javascript file, which is to reload minicart:

```
<script>
  require([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
  ], function (customerData) {
    var sections = ['cart'];
    customerData.invalidate(sections);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You can try with,  var  miniCart = $('[data-block=\'minicart\']'); miniCart.trigger('contentUpdated');

Answer (score 1):

As Rakesh said in the comment you can trigger the content to be updated:

```
miniCart = $('[data-block=\'minicart\']');
miniCart.trigger('contentUpdated');
```

You can see this used in [minicart.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/99e85cbc45223baa3551e4c534b650c0d2c6358b/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js)

### Notes

**Related tip:** To run your script on page load it's better to use domReady! as a dependency rather than use the jquery document ready method. domReady! makes sure other dependant scripts are aware of the dom ready requirement.

Comment: when i call the function for the first time it reload the minicart but, when i try run the function for the second time it didn't do anything

Comment: @Hunter Hmmmm what happens if you extend `Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js` and use `miniCart.sidebar('update');`?